# How to get column of line in file when items have spaces?

Tags: bash

Does anyone know a command that can get me the nth column of a tab-delimited file, when the items in the columns of the file contain spaces? I tried `awk` and `cut`, but I think they are interpreting the spaces in the items as tabs and so are giving me incorrect values. I double checked by manually counting columns and I think this is the case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `cut` should default to tabs as the column separator; awk defaults to runs of spaces or tabs as the field separator. Using `cut` should work if your input really is tab separated.

Answer (score 1):

You can set tab as a delimiter in the `cut` command like this:

```
cut -d$'\t' -f2 file.txt
```

Input (tab separated columns that contain spaces):

```
first item  second item third item
123 456 789 987 654 321 741 852 933
```

Output (when selecting 2nd columnn):

```
second item
987 654 321
```

As you can see, the spaces didn't interfere with the column separation.

Comment: Not sure if this is what the OP is asking for.